# Closing form with Gif throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, datagridview

This is clearly a problem of me not understanding how to properly setup a UI thread, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have a datagridview where I click a button, get the information from the network, and then display it on the datagridview with the new data. While it is on the network I have a form I show with an updating gif, a form I called "loading". Within that form I have the gif updating using the typical OnFrameChanged and m_isAnimating code that is on the internet.

However, no matter what format I use, I always get this exception caught here:

```
    Public loader As New Loading
    Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Try  ' If animation is allowed call the ImageAnimator UpdateFrames method
        ' to show the next frame in the animation.
        Me.Invalidate()
        If m_IsAnimating Then
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
            Me.Refresh()
            'Draw the next frame in the animation.
            Dim aGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
             aGraphics.DrawImage(_AnimatedGif, New Point(0, 0))
                            aGraphics.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException

    End Try
End Sub
```

And it usually says something along the lines of "was accessed from a thread it wasn't created on" or "Cannot access a disposed object.  Object name: 'PictureBox'."

But I don't know why that is, since I am creating a new instance here every time. Here's the button's code:

```
 Private Sub btnSlowSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSlowSearch.Click

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

        'get datatable

        loader.Show()
        BWorkerLoadProp.RunWorkerAsync() 'go get data on network 
        'bworker will update datagridview with new data

        'wait for worker to finish 
        If BWorkerLoadProp.IsBusy Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        End If

        loader.Close()
 End Sub
```

I realize it isn't very good code, but I have tried putting the loader inside the background worker, I have tried whatever. But no matter what the exception is called.

What's the proper way to show another updating form as I do background work?

Comment: After you called loader.Close(), the *loader* object is no longer usable.  So the second time you click the button, your program will always bomb.  Get rid of `As New`, you must create a new Loading instance explicitly with the New operator.

Comment: so "Public loader = New Loading"?

Comment: No, Public loader As Loading.  In your Click event handler: loader = New Loading

Comment: Sorry, but that exception is still being thrown in that setup of "    Public loader As Loading" and loader = New Loading" in the click event. So my form actually never shows on my gui

Comment: There are a lot more bugs in that code, surely some more we haven't seen yet.  Write the kind of code you can understand and maintain.

Comment: While I do understand the sentiment, I unfortunately am being forced outside of that box due to requests of the higher powers that be.

Comment: Is it possible that your `OnFrameChanged` is called after the call to close in the `btnSlowSearch_Click`? I am not sure, but logic seems to suggest to call the ImageAnimator.StopAnimate in the close event of the form that shows the animation.

Comment: @Steve You're absolutely right, after I made my last comment I saw that the "stop animating" boolean is never set to "stop". I changed that, and it dramatically helped.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior documented is difficult to reproduce.
Probably something between the thread switching causes a call to `OnFrameChanged` after the call to close in the `btnSlowSearch_Click`.

In any case logic seems to suggest to call the `ImageAnimator.StopAnimate` in the close event of the form that shows the animation

So looking at your comment above I would add the following to your animator form

```
// Not needed
// Public loader As New Loading

Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try  
        Me.Invalidate()
        If m_IsAnimating Then
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
            Me.Refresh()
            'Draw the next frame in the animation.
            Dim aGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
             aGraphics.DrawImage(_AnimatedGif, New Point(0, 0))
                            aGraphics.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
       .. do not leave this empty or remove altogether
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

   ... if you need to stop the closing you should do it here without stopping the animation

   If m_IsAnimating Then
        ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(AnimatedGif, _
                      New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnFrameChanged)) 


        m_isAnimating = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had something much simpler, but I changed it to your setup here since it looks to be the smarter way to do it. I just tested it with success!

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not the only way to do this but I will provide you the simplest working example in hopes that it will help you to correct your own application.

1) Create a new vb.net windows forms application and add a button (Button1) onto the form.

2) Change the Form1 code to this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If fLoading Is Nothing Then  ' can only show one loading screen at a time
            Dim oLoadingThread As clsLoadingThread = New clsLoadingThread   ' creat new thread
            oLoadingThread.ShowWaitScreen() ' show the loading screen

            '-----------------------------------------
            ' your real processing would go here
            '-----------------------------------------
            For i As Int32 = 0 To 999999
                Application.DoEvents()
            Next
            '-----------------------------------------

            oLoadingThread.CloseLoadingScreen()    ' we are done processing so close the loading form
            oLoadingThread = Nothing    ' clear thread variable
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class clsLoadingThread
    Dim oThread As System.Threading.Thread

    Private Delegate Sub CloseLoadingScreenDelegate()

    Public Sub ShowWaitScreen()
        ' create new thread that will open the loading form to ensure animation doesn't pause or stop
        oThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ShowLoadingForm)
        oThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowLoadingForm()
        Dim fLoading As New frmLoading
        fLoading.ShowDialog()   ' Show loading form
        If fLoading IsNot Nothing Then fLoading.Dispose() : fLoading = Nothing ' loading form should be closed by this point but dispose of it just in case
    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseLoadingScreen()
        If fLoading.InvokeRequired Then
            ' Since the loading form was created on a seperate thread we need to invoke the thread that created it
            fLoading.Invoke(New CloseLoadingScreenDelegate(AddressOf CloseLoadingScreen))
        Else
            ' Now we can close the form
            fLoading.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Public fLoading As frmLoading
End Module
```

3) Add a new form and call it frmLoading. Add a picturebox to the form and set the image to your updating gif.

4) Change the frmLoading code to this:

```
Public Class frmLoading
    Private Sub frmLoading_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        fLoading = Me    ' ensure that the global loading form variable is set here so we can use it later
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmLoading_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        fLoading = Nothing   ' clear the global loading form since the form is being disposed
    End Sub
End Class
```

Normally I would add the clsLoadingThread Class and Module1 Module to their own files but it's easier to show the code to you this way.